# How to extract 3000 images of a user using Twitter API?

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I have been trying to extract images of a user but can only extract 2 images as of now.

```
oauth = OAuth1(CONSUMER_KEY,
            client_secret = CONSUMER_SECRET,
            resource_owner_key = OAUTH_TOKEN,
            resource_owner_secret = OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET)
tend = 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q=from%3Anarendramodi%20filter%3Aimages&src=typd'
response = requests.get(tend, auth = oauth)

tweets = response.json()
links = []
for i in range(len(tweets['statuses'])):
    if 'media' in tweets['statuses'][i]['entities']:
        for j in range(len(tweets['statuses'][i]['entities']['media'])):
            links.append(tweets['statuses'][i]['entities']['media'][j]['media_url'])
```

The following code gives me a list containing 2 links only. I don't know what's the problem here.

**P.S.:** When I was using `tweepy`, I was able to get 17 links only. Here is the code for that:

```
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth)
for status in tweepy.Cursor(api.search, q = 'from:narendramodi filter:images', include_entities=True).items(5000):
    if 'media' in status.entities:
        for image in status.entities['media']:
            f.write(image['media_url'] + '\n')

f.close()
```

Comment: Using the Twitter API, you can only retrieve the 3200 newest tweets of a user. So you are limited to the images in those 3200 tweets which could theoretically be just two or 17. That being said, in your own solution, you definitely need to add *paging* since you won’t get all those 3200 tweets at once (just up to 200).

Comment: Oh, I just saw that you are actually using the search API here (instead of the user timeline). The search API is limited to tweets of the *last seven days*. So you won’t see any tweet before that (which would explain the 17 better). You probably still need paging there though to access all results.

Comment: @poke thanks I'll read about it and try to figure it out. I am relatively new to APIs